# Lookahead in javacc not working

Tags: java, parsing, javacc, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to parse a simple input using JAVACC and I need lookahead but it is not working as expected

```
   LOOKAHEAD(LikeExpression())
    e=LikeExpression()    |     e=InExpression()

LikeExpression():
{..
..}
{

<LIKE>

}

InExpression():
{..
..}
{

[<NOT>]
("(")

}
```

INPUT : "CITY LIKE DELHI"

```
com.sample.ParseException: Encountered " "LIKE" "like "" at line 1, column 35.
Was expecting one of:
"NOT" ...
"(" ...
```

Comment: There is no need for lookahead in this case as the choice between `LikeExpression` and `InExpression` can be made on the basis of the next token.  Also you example is too incomplete to be reasoned about. Please boil your problem down to a *minimal but complete* example and post the whole grammar for that example.

Comment: Can anybody write the one line code for lookahead getToken I am running into a lot problems after reading the documentation

Comment: If you have an example where you think lookahead isn't working the way you expect it should, try turning on the debug_parser and debug_lookahead options. If you are still confused, gradually simplify you grammar until the grammar is as simple as possible while still illustrating the problem. If you still don't understand why the parser behaves as it does, update your question with that simple-as-possible file.